Simulate recursive formula
I'm working on HIVE.
I have the following data:



Date
WholeBudget
Target PocketA
PocketA
PocketB




2024-01-01
60
75%
45
15


2024-01-02
80
75%
60
20


2024-01-03
100
50%
60
40


2024-01-04
110
50%
60
50


2024-01-05
120
50%
60
60


2024-01-06
130
50%
65
65


2024-01-07
140
50%
70
70



Date is an input on already existing data.
WholeBudget and Target PocketA are also inputs (actually already computed values using LAG shenanigans).
PoketA is the goal. Its formula is: PocketA(d) = MAX(PocketA(d-1), WholeBudget(d) x Target(d))
where d is the date on the data line.
PocketB is simply the remainder: PocketB(d) = WholeBudget(d) - PocketA(d)
Whole budget is strictly increasing at varying speed.
Pockets are not allowed to decrease (thus the max in PocketA formula).
Target PocketA can decrease. That's why, sometimes, PocketA is above target and waits for PocketB to catch on.
I don't think PocketA is doable with LAG() as it is referencing the previous value as part of the computation.
I'm working on a WHILE loop over all the dates to get it. Although it's an acceptable solution as the number of dates is capped by the current year (max ~200 working days), it still hurts my soul.
Is there a smarter solution working on hive?
To clarify as requested:
Here is the provided data to reproduce:



Date
WholeBudget
Target PocketA




2024-01-01
60
75%


2024-01-02
80
75%


2024-01-03
100
50%


2024-01-04
110
50%


2024-01-05
120
50%


2024-01-06
130
50%


2024-01-07
140
50%



And here is the expected result:



Date
PocketA
PocketB




2024-01-01
45
15


2024-01-02
60
20


2024-01-03
60
40


2024-01-04
60
50


2024-01-05
60
60


2024-01-06
65
65


2024-01-07
70
70




HiveQL doesn't support recursive queries : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=38572242#content/view/38572242

I'd calculate it naively (Budget * Target) and then use a window function to look back at ALL previous  results (including the current row) and take the max.
WITH
  calc_pa AS
(
  SELECT
    date,
    WholeBudget,
    Target,
    MAX(WholeBudget * Target) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS PocketA
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *,
  WholeBudget - PocketA   AS PocketB
FROM
  calc_pa


Sweet solution!
I wonder what trick would make it work still if the formula had been like PocketA(d) = max( F(PocketA(d-1)) , Budget x Target)
Where F is an actual function, like +5% or +d

@Moroh Then you'd need recursion or iteration, which hive doesn't support.

For this scenario in Hive, a window function approach might be more efficient than a WHILE loop. Here's a potential solution:
Use ROW_NUMBER() to order rows.
Apply MAX() as a window function with an unbounded preceding frame.
SELECT Date, WholeBudget, Target,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Target * WholeBudget / 100 > PrevPocketA 
           THEN Target * WholeBudget / 100
           ELSE PrevPocketA END) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS PocketA,
  WholeBudget - MAX(CASE WHEN Target * WholeBudget / 100 > PrevPocketA 
                         THEN Target * WholeBudget / 100
                         ELSE PrevPocketA END) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS PocketB
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    LAG(PocketA, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS PrevPocketA
  FROM YourTable
) t


This won't use the new values for the pockets in the calculations. It's best to treat the question as not already having pocket values as they're not part of the newly calculated values.

Implemented and indeed.
